# Fixed product tax by category

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, tax, category-attribute

I was looking into a way of setting an EcoTax on products and I noticed that the way people seem to be doing it is by setting a Fixed Product Tax.

My problem with that approach is that it is time consuming. I set up all the settings correctly to enable FPT but my understanding is that now i have to walk through all the products and add a line for FPT to set country, state and tax value? There's gotta be a faster way than that...

So i'm actually wondering if it is possible to set that value onto a category instead and have the products in a given category inherit the value by default (like have it auto filled) but still keep the possibility to change it afterwards on a per product basis.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

And what happens in an import scenario? Let's say i'm importing 4000 products, is it possible to include the FPT as part of the import?